# Efficient way to query database from an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I have an array containing about 400 10-20 character, single string number items. I want to query my database from this array in the most efficient way (on server load and load time) possible. Here is what I have currently but it takes about 4-6 seconds to load the page.

```
foreach(unserialize(mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($database, "SELECT `array` FROM `users` WHERE `id` ='00000001'"))[0]) as $value) {
    $friend_id = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($database, "SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `id` ='".$value."'"))[0];
    if(!empty($friend_id)){
        echo mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($database, "SELECT 'username' FROM `users` WHERE `id` ='".$value."'"))[0] . "<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you storing serialized arrays in the database?

Comment: Yes I am, should I do that or not?

Comment: No, you shouldn't. It creates problems like the one you're having, and it makes your database PHP-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Look out for [JOINs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) in SQL, e.g. at this [page](http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-JOIN.asp).